# Expression expected in PhpStorm when using php variables in JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, php, phpstorm

When I am using changing php variables to JavaScript variables, I am getting "expression expected" error from PhpStorm.

I cannot change the extension of the file to `something.js.php` because I am already using blade template so it should be `blade.php`

[image: This is the first example]

[image: This is the second example]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php $myVar = 5;?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJavascriptVar = <?php echo $myVar; ?>;
    var myJavascriptSecondVar = {{$myVar;}};
    alert(myJavascriptVar + myJavascriptSecondVar);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added a sample html page for more clarification. In PhpStrom the

```html
var myJavascriptVar = <?php echo $myVar; ?>;
```

and

```html
 var myJavascriptSecondVar = {{$myVar;}};
```

statements gives expression expected error.

Comment: does it work when executed? it's just a PHPStorm problem?

Comment: You can set the coding templates etc... in the settings in jetbrains products. You can define witch errors phpstorm should check for, and disable where it shouldnt

Comment: The code works just fine. I am having a trouble PhpStorm

Comment: Please attach/share file that has this issue (using original file name) -- code could be simplified just enough to reproduce the issue. ideally -- create and share sample project (whole project). Right now it's not 100% clear (from these small screenshots) what context it has (file type etc). Full screenshot of the whole editor window (where editor tab with file name/icon is visible) might help as well.

Comment: to get rid of the warning, write `<?php echo 'var myJavascriptVar =  '.$myVar; ?>;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a bug (incomplete inter-language handling) in PhpStorm.

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24968
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25739
- possibly some another (from "Related" list) as well

Watch those tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress. Right now they are not assigned to any specific future versions.

Comment: -- var myJavascriptSecondVar = {{$myVar;}}; -- 
For this statement I can understand there is a bug for laravel template. However  -- var myJavascriptVar = <?php echo $myVar; ?>; -- for this statement I think PhpStorm should not give this error because it should be very common I guess.

Comment: Yes .. but that works without extra warnings in `.php` files ... but here you have `.blade.php` which is a completely different File Type (in IDE eyes). Every language is implemented/handled *separately* -- PHP+JS may have special exclusions already in place; now it needs to be extended to cover Blade files as well. I may only suggest to submit another ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) for this moment.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two workarounds:

**1. function**

```
function blade(_)
{
    return _;
}

var data = blade({{ $data }});
// or ES6 arrow function
var data = (_ => _)({{ $data }});
```

**2. array**

```js
var data = [{{ $data }}].pop();
// or
var data = [{{ $data }}][0];
```

Comment: var data = [{{ $data }}][0];  //this is perfect for me